# MySQL - Count if the values of two column is different

Tags: mysql, count

`My Table
colA | colB
0    | 0
1    | 0 
0    | 1 
1    | 1`

if the values of `colA` and `colB` are different then count.

expected result: `2` (row 2 and row 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as different
FROM tablename
WHERE colA != colB
```